# Asserting two instance in java with limited properties

Tags: java, junit, verification, assertions

I am developing a verification system to compare two instance of a same class.

I am using Reflection assertion to compare the properties of instances. But sometimes we could not expect exact values of some properties like system generated time, random numbers etc.

Example : Consider a class which has properties as follows.

Class => TransactionDetails

Properties = > 1: transactionID
    2 : transactionStatus
    3: transactionTime

*Actual instance of TransactionDetails*

```
1: transactionID : 987DFGAS876
2: transactionStatus : SUCCESS
3: transactionTime : 2015-10-15T15:46:53.378+05:30
```

*Expected instance of TransactionDetails*

```
1: transactionID : 987DFGAS876
2: transactionStatus : SUCCESS
3: transactionTime : 2015-10-15T15:39:29.127+05:30
```

Result of assertion is => **false** because of the difference in time.

So, If I give my expected instance like follows,

*Expected instance of TransactionDetails with limited(required) values*

```
1: transactionID : 987DFGAS876
2: transactionStatus : SUCCESS
```

Result of assertion is => **false** because the difference in time ( null & 2015-10-15T15:46:53.378+05:30)

So, in my case i need to compare only the enriched 2 values with the actual instance, need to skip the properties
which the user don't want to assert the values.

To achieve this I am doing reflection to get all properties and check the enriched properties in the expected instance with actual instance.

But this will lead to performance issues for large instances. Is there any easy
solution for this requirement?

Please share your thoughts to solve this, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can flag fields that you want to compare with a custom annotation. Then you can get if you should compare the field by Reflection aswell:

```
@CheckAnnotation
String tocompare = "SomeTimeDataString";
...
Annotation[] annotations = field.getDeclaredAnnotations();

for(Annotation annotation : annotations){
    if(annotation instanceof CheckAnnotation){
        //Compare the field
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Friwi, But the verifier doesn't have a privilege to enhance the characters of field in user class, Input to my functionality will be only two things, 1: Fully enriched actual value, 2 : Limited enriched expected value. I need to compare only the limited enriched value in expected instance to actual instance.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a specific need for reflection? You could simply generate a `equals` and `hashcode`method checking at a limited subset of fields.

In eclipse : menu Source > Generate hashcode() and equals()... then check the fields you want to compare.

That way will avoid the performance issues due to reflection...